# scanner.nextLine() results in an error when user inputs 1 - 2. How do I allow my program to accept this input as 1?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to allow a user to input a single number or an unsolved equation as their input. My program is supposed to take user input by assigning Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()) to a variable. When the user inputs 2 - 1, I get an error java.lang.AssertionError:. Is this a limitation of scanner, or am I implementing my code incorrectly? I have attempted to assign the user input to a second variable after the fact in hopes that that would resolve the problem I am having, but am getting the same error. Can someone give me some help?

Comment: Please post your actual code and sample output from a test run as my tinfoil hat prevents me from viewing your code via psychic powers. Stack Overflow questions should include code samples that demonstrate the issue at hand. Learn more by reading the [help file](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.nextLine()`, as the name kinda gives away, reads one entire line. It returns `"2 - 1"` as a string. `Integer.parseInt()` parses integers; it is not a calculator. It can't parse 2 - 1.

This sounds like homework; the homework assignment would then presumably involve you writing a program that can read, in sequence, '2', '-', and '1', read these into multiple variables, and do the subtraction operation.

Scanner is not a great solution to this; if you must use it, you have to mess with the delimiter to ensure you get 2, -, and 1, in that order - out of the box, scanners split on spaces, so the input "2 - 1" would result in 3 tokens, but "2-1" (without the spaces) is one token, not what you want when writing a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the characters of the line until you find a character that is not a digit and just parse the portion you have already processed.

```
private static int parseIntPart(final String str) {
    final int len = str.length();
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            sb.append(c);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
}
public static void main(final String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = parseIntPart(scan.nextLine());
}
```